# Pronunciation of numbers in address

Tags: numbers, speech, ordinal-numbers

When I say the name of a street with “at”, like “at 12 Oxford St”, should I pronounce the number as cardinal or ordinal? And if it is ordinal, do I get it right that it still must always be written without the article, but pronounced with it?

Answer (score 1):

Always a cardinal, with no article. Pronounce it as "at twelve Oxford Street".

Comment: Are you confusing it with days in the month?

Comment: @KateBunting No. I don't know why you'd think that, seeing as I gave an example. And what relevance would my answer have to days in the month anyway?

Comment: You asked whether "it still must always be written without the article, but pronounced with it." I wondered if you were thinking of 'June 12' being pronounced as 'June the twelfth'. We don't use an article with house numbers.